# find the optimal value of the cost function?

Tags: linear-programming

Use duality to find the optimal value of the cost function in the following
linear programming problem:

Max. $x + y + z$

such that $3x + 2y + 2z = 1,$

$x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0, z ≥ 0$

One of my friend said me that used Largangian and dual function but im not getting

Im completely struck Pliz help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual is

$$\min p$$

subject to $$3p \ge 1, 2p \ge 1, 2p \ge 1$$

Solve this optimization problem and use strong duality to make conclusion.

Comment: thanks u  @siong  is $p= 1/2$ ??

Comment: yes, optimal $p$ is $\frac12$. Practise writing down dual. :) Also you might like to visualize what is the set of the optimal solution in the original optimization problem.

Comment: okss thanks u so much @Siong Thye Goh

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [Simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm):
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|rr}
      & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 &   C  & \text{ratio} \\ \hline
  s &   3 &   2 &   2 &   1 &              1/2 \\\hdashline
      &   -1 &  -1 & -1 & 0 &              \\ \hline
  x_2 \text{ or } x_3   &  3/2 &  1 &  1 &  \color{red}{1/2} &              \\\hdashline
       &   1/2 &   0 &   0 &   \color{blue}{1/2} &
\end{array}$$
So, $u(0,\color{red}{1/2},0)=u(0,0,\color{red}{1/2})=\color{blue}{1/2}$ is maximum.